# PyQt5 QTableWidget inserting pandas header data

Tags: python, pandas, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I'am having trouble inserting the header data into QTableWidget. Currently setting all data to be uneditable.

This gets the rest of the data into the Qtablewidget but leaves out the headers:

```
df = pandas.read_csv(path[0], delimiter=',', sep="  " + 't', engine='python')
for index, row in coordsdf.iterrows():
    numrows = self.qtable_widget.rowCount() # Create a empty row at bottom of table
    self.qtable_widget.insertRow(numrows) # Create a empty row at bottom of table
    self.qtable_widget.setColumnCount(len(coordsdf.columns)) #set column count to match the data
    for column in coordsdf.columns:
        h = coordsdf.columns.get_loc(column) #find which column you are working with
        x = str(coordsdf.iloc[index, h]) #get that columns value
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(x)
        item.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled) #make cell uneditable
        self.qtable_widget.setItem(numrows, h, item) #insert into Qtablewidget
```

Comment: You'd better create a model for your tablewidget. See this: https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/blob/master/questions/44603119/PandasModel.py

Comment: @FarhoodET already made a model, didn't include the code because this is the only section of code that is pertinent to the question (as far as I'am aware, could be wrong)